# How to retrieve values from a table after executing sub queries

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Here is the image of schema of the database for which I am trying to formulate the queries.
[Database Schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hUQo6.png)

The query is:-
Find the name of faculty member, department who taught the maximum number of distinct classes.

`SELECT MAX(fidCount) FROM(
     SELECT COUNT(fid) AS fidCount FROM class GROUP BY fid) AS C`

Which returns 6, now I want to know how can i find the fid which counts to 6 i.e. Max number of classes taught by a teacher.

Answer (score 0):

If I have read this correctly you want to return data so it has the fid next to the fidcount.

This should fix it

```
SELECT fid, MAX(fidCount) FROM(
 SELECT fid, COUNT(fid) AS fidCount FROM class GROUP BY fid) AS C
```

Comment: No this returns the first fid in the table not the one next to MAX(fidCount), I have tried it before.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code to calculate the number of distinct classes taught by each faculty member:

```
select faculty.fid, faculty.fname, count(distinct cname) UnqCls
from class inner join faculty on class.fid = faculty.fid
group by faculty.fid, faculty.fname;
```

Then use the mysql ranking function to find the fid, fname with the greatest UnqCls.

Answer (score 0):

I'm amazed at how many issues a qualify statement solves...are you using Teradata?

Because then it's as simple as ...

```
SELECT fid, fidcount FROM(
SELECT fid, COUNT(fid) AS fidCount FROM class GROUP BY fid) C 
qualify row_number() over(order by fidcount desc)=1
```

Another alternative could be to find the maximum fidcount...and then inner join it back to a record of fids with their ficounts:

```
SELECT FID, FIDCOUNT FROM 
(SELECT fid, fidcount FROM(
SELECT fid, COUNT(fid) AS fidCount FROM class GROUP BY fid) C )D
INNER JOIN (SELECT MAX(fidCount) AS FIDCOUNT_MAX FROM(
SELECT COUNT(fid) AS fidCount FROM class GROUP BY fid) AS C)E
ON D.FIDCOUNT=E.FIDCOUNT_MAX
```